# No output on pins in pic24f

Tags: pic, led, mplab

I can't get my pic24f04kl100 to turn on an LED at all. The below code is as simple as possible and it still doesn't turn on the LED on pin 6.

### Code

```
#include <xc.h>

#define LED LATBbits.LATB4
#define LEDans ANSBbits.ANSB4
#define LEDtris TRISBbits.TRISB4

/* Setting up configuration bits */
_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRCPLL & IESO_OFF);  // FRC w/PLL and int./ext. switch disabled
_FOSC(POSCMD_XT & FCKSM_CSECMD);    // Pri. OSC XT mode and clk. switch on, fail-safe off
_FWDT(FWDTEN_OFF);                  // Watchdog timer off

void initialise();
void delay(int i);

void main() {                      // Main program loop
    initialise();                  // Intialise PIC
    while (1) {                    // Infinite loop
        LED = 1;                   // Set LED high
        LED = 0;                   // Set LED low
    }
}

void initialise() {                // Configures the PIC
    OSCCONbits.NOSC = 0b111;        // Fast RC Oscillator with Postscaler and PLL module
    delay(100);
    CLKDIVbits.RCDIV = 0b000;       // Set clock div 1:1
    delay(100);
    LEDans = 0;
    delay(100);
    LEDtris = 0;                    // Make LED an output
    delay(100);
    LED = 0;                        // Set LED low
}

void delay(int i) {
    while(i--);
}
```

### PICkit 3 Output

```
*****************************************************

Connecting to MPLAB PICkit 3...
Firmware Suite Version.....01.27.04
Firmware type..............dsPIC33F/24F/24H

Target detected
Device ID Revision = 0

The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x3ff
configuration memory

Programming...
Programming/Verify complete
```

Comment: I haven't messed with PICs in ages but I think you also have to enable the register. Something like `PORTBENbits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default B4 pin is analog. Configure it as digital by clearing the ANSB register, bit4

NOTE: Although clearing the bit DID NOT fix the problem. Moving to another pin (with less features) did. So I (fossum) made the assumption that this was at least on some level the correct answer.

Comment: Set the clocksource using `Configuration bits`, not in code.  Switching by `OSCCON = 0x70` is not as simple as you use. Also try to add a one-cicle delay by adding `NOP();` after configure port before you write to port.

Comment: I've updated the code above, still no luck. I can't even debug, so how do I tell the thing is even going through clock cycles?

Comment: Okay, although it doesn't print what I want it seems the UART prints, so I know it's running.

Answer (score 0):

The LED is blinking, but it's blinking very fast, try to put some delay between LED turn on and LED turn off.

Try this:

`void main() {                      // Main program loop
    initialise();                  // Intialise PIC
    while (1) {                    // Infinite loop
        LED = 1;                   // Set LED high
        delay(50000);              //wait LED on time
        LED = 0;                   // Set LED low
        delay(50000);              //wait LED off time 
    }
}`